# is there any way to store multiple emails with pre define input field value in mongo db?

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I created one form which has an email field for taking multiple user email ids with a comma ',' and I want to store that emails into my DB collection. I already fetch one email id at signup time and that I want to display as the default email and if user want to multiple emails then input be like- default@email.com,another@email.com

e.g when the add_alert.js file render then user email id which is already in the user collection that displays in the input field and if a user wants to add another email then he/she can enter via comma seperator and submit the form. and after submitting both email ids store in array in my db.

I used MongoDB, nodejs, express-js and semantic UI for my project.

aert.js - modal file:

```
var alertSchema = new mongo.Schema({
  ......
  user:{
    type:mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  email:Arrays, // the email id which is for sending alert error 
  .....
})
```

add_alert.pug

```
p.lead.inline_block
            span.muted.definition_header Enter your email:
          .ui.input.inline_block.required
            input(required='', value=alert.email type='email',disabled=req.params.email,name='email', style="width: auto")
```

I am not getting predefine value if I set value=user.emails in the input filed, then how it would be possible to store another email

Comment: `type='email'` is most likely going to cause issues if you're expecting comma-separated emails as input and not just one.

Comment: that's not an issue you can use multiple attribute in the input field. but how can I display pre-email value want to store user enter email in dB and my pre-define email also